# Get more logged-in information in Zend Framework2

Tags: authentication, zend-framework2, identity, credentials

I'm implementing a log-in form by using Zend Framework 2.
I have a "user" table in mysql database: `user(user_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,email-address, password)`.

The user will input email-address and password.
My web application will call `authenticate()` method with the identity is email-address, the credential is password.

If the validation success, `getIdentity()` return the email-address.
But not only the email-address, I want to know the user_id field to use for other query after logged-in.

How can I get more information in my "user" table?
I don't want to query from database twice. (once for authentication, once for user_id).
Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just authenticate the correct user call the `AuthenticationService` and the method `getStorage` with will return you the storage container for the current user. just pass a object or your user entity in this and after calling `$this->identity()` you should become your custom identity object.

```
$authService = $this->getServiceManager('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');
if ( // user auth success ) {

    $userObject = array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'baz' => 'bas'
    );

    $authService->getStorage()->write( $userObject );
}
```

now by calling `$this->identity()` u get the following output

```
var_dump( $this->identity() );

//output
array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => 'bas'
)
```

Comment: I think you don't really understand my question.
I know how to store the information in SessionStorage.
But I don't know how to get the information to store in $userObject.
I understand that zendframework just use a "SELECT * " query to get all informations for a 'email-address' and check the password after that.
The problem is that the "user_id" would not be returned from the result of authentication.
Zend Framework don't care anything other than email-address and password

Answer (score 0):

Sometime like this

```
// Set the input credential values (e.g., from a login form)
$authAdapter
    ->setIdentity('my_username')
    ->setCredential('my_password')

// Print the result row
print_r($authAdapter->getResultRowObject());
/* Output:
user table

Array
(
    [user_id] => 1
    [email-address] => my_username
    [password] => my_password
)
```

Also read more manual: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.authentication.adapter.dbtable.html